# weight_decay is not a valid argument, kwargs should be empty for `optimizer_experimental.Optimizer`. with tf.keras on a remote flask web app

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras, conv-neural-network

I made a flask web app that lets the user upload an image and be classified by a CNN with Tensorflow Keras, and it works on my computer when I run the script locally. The thing is, when I try to upload it on a remote server (Like the HuggingFace API or a PythonAnywhere web) it returns this error whenever I try to do a prediction with an image.

Here's the app code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import os
import cv2

MB = 10
IMAGE_WIDTH = IMAGE_HEIGHT = 224
MODELO = 'ptctrn_v1.6.h5'

app = Flask(__name__) #crea instancia de flask

app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGHT'] = MB * 1024 * 1024

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = ['png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'jfif', 'webp']

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
        filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


def read_image(filename):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT))
    return img

def modelCall(DIR):
    img = cv2.imread(DIR)
    resize = tf.image.resize(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB),(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT))
    ptctrn = load_model(MODELO)
    y_gorrito = ptctrn.predict(np.expand_dims(resize/255, 0))

    return f'La probabilidad de que la imagen tenga un patacón es del: {round(float(y_gorrito), 2)*100}%'


@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/predict', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        try:
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = file.filename
                file_path = os.path.join('static','images', filename)
                file.save(file_path)
                result = modelCall(file_path)

                return render_template('predict.html', product = result, user_image = file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            return "No ha sido posible leer el archivo. Por favor revisa si la extensión de archivo es correcta (.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .jfif o .webp): ", str(e)
    
    return render_template('predict.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

So everytime I try to do a prediction, the exception is called with the title's sentence, what can I do? I've tried to find a similar problem here, but I haven't found something that can fully help me, there is one recommendation of checking that the version on my pc is the same as the remote server, I uploaded my project on replit specifying the module versions i locally have, and it didn't work either.

Comment: in which like the exception is been thrown?

Comment: The log page isn't giving me any insight, but I'd assume that the exception happens when importing the tf keras model, since weight decay and optimizer are attributes the model could have

Comment: I dont see any `fit()` call, so idk why are you using an optimizer

Comment: The model is already trained, it is loading with an .h5 file, I thought it may have something to do with some model setting, but I have no idea